# Can't access recently saved data, before POST request ends - node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Recently I faced a problem where I couldn't get a recent insertion using MongoDB (mongoose) in node.js.

```
    app.post("/addEvent", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new Event(req.body);
    myData.save().then(item => {
        res.send("Event saved to database!");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
    });

    Event.find({categoryName:req.body.categoryName}, function(err, events) {
        if (err) throw err;

        Car.find({categoryName:req.body.categoryName}, function(err, cars) {
            if (err) throw err;

            /**some_code_here**/

        });
    });

    some_foo(app, req.body.categoryName);
    res.redirect(301, '/groups' + req.body.categoryName);  
});
```

So, when I try to collect all the events via `Event.find({})`, I get zero events.
But after the request ends, I can see my event in the database.
What I want is to have access to the recently added event inside the POST request. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for recent saved Event, you must wait for callback of your myData.save() function. If you don't wait for it, Event.find() will be fire in parralel of your myData.save()

try :

```
        app.post("/addEvent", (req, res) => {
            var myData = new Event(req.body);
            myData.save().then(item => {
                //res.send("Event saved to database!");

                Event.find({categoryName:req.body.categoryName}, function(err, events) {
                if (err) throw err;

                Car.find({categoryName:req.body.categoryName}, function(err, cars) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    /**some_code_here**/

                });

                some_foo(app, req.body.categoryName);
                res.redirect(301, '/groups' + req.body.categoryName);  
                })
            });
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
            });
        });
```

And if you want to wait for your Car.find() before res.redirect(), you must wait for Car.find() callback...
Welcome to 'callback hell' (you can search on google this).

In recent nodejs version, you can use await/async functionnality to help you with it. See example : https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I had already tried this, but I did that after the `res.send()` call, so I messed it up. New to node.js as you can see!

Comment: Yes, you can just use ONE res.send or.res.redirect or res.whatever else...